# Why when I Customizing my theme it wont work on the blade?

Tags: laravel, tailwind-css

I'm working on a Laravel project and I'm using Tailwind CSS for it.
What I'm trying to do is to add a costume color in order to use it in the class in the HTML just like it is said in the documentation:  https://tailwindcss.com/docs/background-color

I have added a color like this:

tailwind.config.js

```
    theme: {
        extend: {
            fontFamily: {
                sans: ["Nunito", ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans],
            },
            colors: {
                emerald: "#2dd4bf",
            },
        },
    },
```

page.blade.php

```
<nav class:"bg-emerald">
....
</nav>
```

The color of the navbar won't change.

How can I fix it?

Comment: It may be just  a typo but in HTML you assign a value to an attribute with `=` instead of `:`. `<nav class="bg-emerald">`

Answer (score 0):

try executing (in the terminal)

```
npm run watch
```

or

```
npm run dev
```